# Blank Servlet with Stored Procedures

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, stored-procedures, oracle11g

i'm pretty new at programming, so its a bit hard for me x.x, but i'm trying to execute a login(JSP) with a stored procedure on java (servlet), sadly the servlet page only gives me a blank page and doesn't redirect me to the home page homeAlumno.jsp(JSP with just a Hello World at the moment), i'm using netbeans IDE 8.2 (with Tomcat Server) and the DB is Oracle 11g Express Edition with a few tables, any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

pd: first post , sorry if i post something wrong :'D

and heere is the code

login.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Login CEM</title>
    </head>
    <body style="text-align: center">
        <h1>Menú CEM</h1>
        <form method="POST" action="serv_login">
            <input type="text" name="usuario"  placeholder="Nombre"/>
            <input type="password" name="pass"  placeholder="Password" />
            <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Class Conexion (Connection)

```
package modelo;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

    public class Conexion {
        private static Connection cnx = null;
       public static Connection obtener() throws SQLException,    ClassNotFoundException {
      if (cnx == null) {
         try {
         Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
         cnx =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "system", "123");
     } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new SQLException(ex);
     } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        throw new ClassCastException(ex.getMessage());
     }
  }
  return cnx;
 }
    public static void cerrar() throws SQLException {
          if (cnx != null) {
             cnx.close();
     }
   }
}
```

serv_login.java (servlet)

```
package controlador;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import modelo.Conexion;

/**
*
* @author asd
 */
@WebServlet(name = "serv_login", urlPatterns = {"/serv_login"})
public class serv_login extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
 * methods.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,    HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    try {

        String usuario = request.getParameter("usuario");
        String pass = request.getParameter("pass");



        CallableStatement stmt = Conexion.obtener().prepareCall("{call LoginJava(?,?)}");

        stmt.setString(1, usuario);
        stmt.setString(2, pass);


        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        RequestDispatcher rd;

        rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");

        while(rs.next()) {

            if(rs.getString("NOMBRE_ALUMN").equals(request.getParameter("usuario")) && rs.getString("PASS_ALUMN").equals(request.getParameter("pass"))){                                            
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("homeAlumno.jsp"); 
                    rd.forward(request, response);  
                }else{
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");  
                    rd.forward(request, response);
                } 

            }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.getMessage();

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(serv_login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        ex.getMessage();
    }

}

// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
/**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Returns a short description of the servlet.
 *
 * @return a String containing servlet description
 */
@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}// </editor-fold>

}
```

Stored Procedure (Oracle DB)

```
create or replace procedure LoginJava(usuario ALUMNO.USU_ALUMN%type,
contraseña ALUMNO.PASS_ALUMN%type)                              
as 
    v_usuario ALUMNO.USU_ALUMN%type;
    v_contraseña ALUMNO.PASS_ALUMN%type;
begin
    select USU_ALUMN, PASS_ALUMN into v_usuario, v_contraseña from ALUMNO
    where USU_ALUMN = usuario and PASS_ALUMN = contraseña;           
    return;
end;
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you do:

```
rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");

... some code ...

request.getRequestDispatcher("homeAlumno.jsp"); 
rd.forward(request, response);
```

The line with `request.getRequestDispatcher("homeAlumno.jsp")` just creates a brand new `RequestDispatcher` which is then thrown away (as it is not saved to any variable). And in the next line you just forward to `login.jsp`.

Try to do the following:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("homeAlumno.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Another thing: in your loop you can theoretically make several forwards (if your procedure returns more than one record). I'd add a break (or replace `while` with `if`) just in case.

And one more thing: I'm not a great specialist in Oracle stored procedures syntax, but it seems that you don't return any result set from your procedure, so your loop body will not be executed at all (even once).

Try doing something like this:

```
select count(*) CNT from ALUMNO
where USU_ALUMN = usuario and PASS_ALUMN = contraseña;
```

And then (instead your `while` loop):

```
rs.next();
if (rs.getInt("CNT") > 0) {
    // .. there is such a user, do the forward
} else {
    // no such user, or password mismatch
}
```

A couple of recommendations, if you don't mind.

First, it looks like you are planning to store your passwords in plain text in your database. That is a bad idea: use a hash with a salt, for instance something like BCrypt. Here is more information: https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2013/11/20/serious-security-how-to-store-your-users-passwords-safely/

Also, you are reinventing the wheel here with password authentication. If this is not just a student project that is going to be thrown away in a couple of days, I would recommend you to look at Spring Security (standalone or in Spring Boot) or a similar security framework. That makes authentication much easier.